# Data filtering problem with multiple dependent users in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter data with some particular condition in **Django**.

my `models.py`:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Industry = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Industry(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='industry_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    license = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    industry_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(myCustomeUser, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    i_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
```

my `views.py`:

```
@method_decorator(industry_required, name='dispatch')
class industryDetails(DetailView):

    model = Industry
    template_name = 'app/industryDetails.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Industry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Industry, user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        Employee_list = Employee.objects.order_by('id')

        context['employee_table'] = Employee_list
        return context
```

Here I fetch all `Employee`'s data in my code with `Employee.objects.order_by('id')`.But I need to fetch only those `Employee`'s data, which only associate with that particular `Industry` which I am currently visiting in the `Detailsview`. How can I filter those particular data only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs for the relationship fields.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

For your view it should be something like:

```
# self.object is the instance of Industry
context['employee_table'] = self.object.employee_set.all()
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, now it is working smoothly!